# Javascript strings manipulation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this below:

```
var st = "ROAM-Synergy-111-222-LLX "
```

It can have any no. of terms before the numeric values ..ie. its possible formats are:

```
var st = "SSI-ROAM-Synergy-111-222-LLX "     or
var st = "LCD-SSI-ROAM-Synergy-111-222-LLX"  etc..
```

Now I need to fetch only the terms before numeric values in this string. ie.
 "SSI-ROAM-Synergy" or "LCD-SSI-ROAM-Synergy"

I am using like this:

```
var finalString = st.split("-");
```

but how to get only the terms before numeric values.

Comment: Could there also be strings without any numeric values?

Comment: no no..the original string must have some numeric codes.. i.e "111-222-LLX" or "333-444-LLX" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
var myval = st.match(/^\D+(?=-)/)[0];
//=> SSI-ROAM-Synergy OR LCD-SSI-ROAM-Synergy
```

**Explanation:**

```
^ assert position at start of the string
\D+ match any character that's not a digit [^0-9]
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible
(?=-) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
- matches the character - literally
```

Comment: one thing i noticed is..if I pass this string ie. "nLight-SSI-RELOC-RTLED-Synergy-345-777-LLA  Replacement" ....then it is returning only "nLight-SSI-RELOC-RTLED"     Can u pls check ?

Comment: It actually returns `nLight-SSI-RELOC-RTLED-Synergy` when input is `nLight-SSI-RELOC-RTLED-Synergy-345-777-LLA Replacement` Is that incorrect?

Comment: Thanks for confirming again.  I am using this in my code and its the only issue i am facing...let me check again..i might be doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

try with the following code

```
<script>
        var yourString = "ROAM-Synergy-111-222-LLX ";
        var output=retriveStartString(yourString);
        alert(output);

    function retriveStartString(inputString){
        var newString="";
        for (i=0;i<inputString.length;i++) {
            var subStr=inputString.substr(i,1);
            //alert(subStr);
            if(subStr.charCodeAt(0)>=48 && subStr.charCodeAt(0)<=57){
                break;
            }
            else{
                newString+=subStr;
            }
        }
        return newString;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b="LCD-SSI-ROAM-Synergy-111-222-LLX".match(/^.+?-[0-9]/)[0].split("-");
b.pop();
```

Here output of `b` will be `["LCD", "SSI", "ROAM", "Synergy"]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using a combination of indexOf, match and substr.

```
var st = "ROAM-Synergy-111-222-LLX";
var lIdx = st.indexOf(st.match(/-\d/));
console.log(st.substr(0, (lIdx >= 0) ? lIdx : st.length));
```