# JavaScript strings manipulations

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this below:

```
var stOrig= "ROAM-Synergy-111-222-LLX" ;
```

There can be any no. of "alphabetic" terms before numeric values `111-222`..
There may or may not be any numeric values i.e the string can also be simply like this: 
`"ROAM-Synergy-LCD-ROAM"`.

if there are numeric values then I am using this

```
var myval = st.match(/^\D+(?=-)/)[0];
```

to get only the alphabetic terms before the numeric values. Its working fine till here.

But if suppose string does not contains any numeric values then my regular expression returns one less term i.e
Say the original string is: `"ROAM-Synergy-LCD-ROAM"` (without any numbers in it.)
Now if is use above reg expression...then it will return only `"ROAM-Synergy-LCD"`
..
so first I need to check for any numeric values in original string.. and if string contains numeric values then I use above reg exp...but please suggest If string does not contain numeric values then what reg expression to use..

Comment: ...and this was precisely the reason I wrote my comment [to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21822958/20670)... :)

Comment: yes I agree :) ..actually there was some code changes that may lead to this situation ...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var myval = st.match(/^\D+(?=-|$)/)[0];
```

The `$` matches at the end of the string.

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/yM5pN0).